# Why the Bessel functions form a complete orthogonal system?

Tags: orthogonality, bessel-functions

Bessel functions multipied with $\sqrt{\rho}$

$$\sqrt\rho J_\nu(x_{\nu n}\frac{\rho}{a})$$

have orthogonality on $[0, a]$. $x_{\nu n}$ is the nth root of $J_\nu(x)$

$$\int^a_0 \rho J_\nu \left( x_{\nu n'}\frac{\rho}{a} \right)J_\nu \left( x_{\nu n}\frac{\rho}{a} \right)\, d\rho = \frac{a^2}{2}[J_{\nu+1}(x_{\nu n})]^2\delta_{n'n} \tag{1}$$

$\delta$ is Kronecker delta.

[Classical Electrodynamics Third Edition](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Classical+Electrodynamics%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471309321#description-section) mentions because Bessel functions form a complete orthogonal system, any abtriary functions can be represent as

$$f(\rho) = \sum^\infty_{n = 1}A_{\nu n}J_\nu\left( x_{\nu n} \frac{\rho}{a} \right) \tag{2}$$

**The orthogonity we get from (1) is $A_{\nu n} \sqrt{\rho} J_\nu\left( x_{\nu n} \frac{\rho}{a} \right)$. Why the basises are $A_{\nu n}J_\nu\left( x_{\nu n} \frac{\rho}{a} \right)$ instead of $A_{\nu n} \sqrt{\rho} J_\nu\left( x_{\nu n} \frac{\rho}{a} \right)$ in (2)**?

Comment: I guess it’s orthogonality in a different inner product, namely $$(f,g) := \int_0^a fg \rho d \rho$$

Comment: What does "different inner product" mean? Can this orthogonality compose arbitrary functions?

Comment: You assumed the inner product $(f,g) = \int fg d\rho$, whereas it seems that the inner product I wrote is being used. It can be used to decompose arbitrary radial functions

Comment: Is there any reference about $\int fg\rho\,d\rho$ that it can be used to decompose arbitrary radial functions?

Comment: When I said radial it should have been 'function of 1 variable' (kind of the same thing.) You might want to start at the resources in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fourier-BesselSeries.html . There are many books on Bessel functions like Watson's "Treatise on the theory of Bessel Functions". There is probably also something in Chapter 4 of E. M. Stein's "Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces".

Comment: Also, it seems that pointwise convergence can be found here: https://ocw.snu.ac.kr/sites/default/files/NOTE/2745.pdf and L^2 convergence can be found here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2027444 . But they do not look simple.

Comment: Thank you for providing the resources. I have quickly and roughly read the two documents. Both of them only mention $\sqrt{x}J_\nu(x)$ forms a complete orthogonal system, no $J_\nu(x)$. Does this mean that Jackson wrote the wrong equation?

Comment: Not really, its just a matter of notation. $(\sqrt x f, \sqrt x g)$ in the usual $L^2$ inner product is $(f,g)$ in the inner product I wrote. E.g. this [paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/36/1/015016) uses the weighted inner product. Also in general for identities of special functions you can try looking here https://dlmf.nist.gov/ (but there are no proofs)

Comment: I am confused. $\sqrt{x}$ here is a variable of $f$ and $g$. Why it can be "weight"? Take $\sin$ and $\cos$ for example. $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are orthogonal in $[0, 2\pi]$ but $\sqrt{x}\sin x$ and $\sqrt{x}\cos x$ are not.

Comment: I use [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+J_2%285.13562230184068+*+x%2F10000%29J_2%2814.7959517823513+*+x%2F10000%29+dx+from+0+to+10000) to get numeric results. It seems that $J_\nu(x_{\nu n}\frac{\rho}{a})$ and $J_\nu(x_{\nu m}\frac{\rho}{a})$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: Ah, I saw the introduction of the orthogonal polynomials with weight functions. However, the question is still there. If a series of functions are orthogonal with weight functions, can their unweighted functions become the basis of Hilbert space?

Comment: It is possible to be a basis of the Hilbert space with the weighted inner product. This is not true for all weights, but it is true in this case, because you are considering functions on a compact set $[0,a]$. See Theorem 3.4 in [Ernst, O. G., Mugler, A., Starkloff, H.-J., & Ullmann, E. (2011). On the convergence of generalized polynomial chaos expansions. doi:10.1051/m2an/2011045](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/esaim-mathematical-modelling-and-numerical-analysis/article/abs/on-the-convergence-of-generalized-polynomial-chaos-expansions/81E3C4C4AD0D670B519C37165121DAA0)

Comment: From Exercise 8.7 of [T. J. Sullivan's "Introduction to Uncertainty Quantification"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-23395-6), if you choose the weight to be the pdf of a lognormal distribution, then you can find infinitely many orthogonal polynomials but they will not form a basis